# CANopen windows library, multiple devices

Tags: c#, windows, canopen

I am going to write Windows application (for commercial use) which will send/receive and trace CANopen messages.

The problem is I don't know what devices will be used by users of this app.
Currently I have one requirement to support only USB-CAN devices.
However there is many vendors of such devices and everyone has other api/library/dll to use theirs devices.

(By the way, the problem is because I have to use Windows.
As I know on Linux is SocketCAN and everything is more standardized :-()

I don't know which library should I use. Could you recomend me something.
Of course this library should support as many vendors (and drivers) as possible.
Second requirement is this library shall compile to IL or somehow I can use this library in my C# application.

I have done small research:

- The most popular is CAN Festival but it is abandoned project, however there is a few forks.
- There is CANopen for .NET 
  But support only PEAK devices and state is prealpha
- CANopen for Python
  Support more devices but state is also alpha and I don't know if I can use this library in my c# application. Maybe when I use IronPython.
- I also found this library: http://www.emtas.de/en/allgemein/csharpapi. It is commercial, but If support many devices I can buy It. Anyone has used it before??

Answer (score 1):

We are using and have licensed the Swedish [datalink.se CANopen library](http://www.datalink.se/) and it works very well for us. But honestly we are only using the CAN interface driver layer on Windows, for accessing a range of devices like Lawicel, Kvaser, IXXAT a.s.o. I haven't looked at the CANopen parts so much.

I looked at other CANopen SW stacks, too, back then, but like you I wasn't happy about CAN Festival. So what we do in our [Kickdrive software](https://kickdrive.blogspot.com) is that we implemented just the amount of CANopen that we really need. See my answer in the post [How to program a simple CANopen layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232624).

Depending on what are your actual requirements, this might be good enough already, or even the best approach.